# How can I get user directly from discord API?

Tags: discord, discord.js, fetch-api

I've been looking around for code that works like this one:

```js
const fetchUser = async id => {
    const response = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/v9/users/(USER ID)', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bot ' + (BOT TOKEN)
        }
    })
    return JSON.parse(await response.json())
}
console.log(fetchUser())
```

I'm trying to get something like this:

```js
{
  "id": "000000000000000001",
  "username": "8",
  "avatar": null,
  "discriminator": "0001",
  "public_flags": 0,
  "banner": null,
  "banner_color": null,
  "accent_color": null
}
```

This is the error/log I get

```js
Promise { <pending> }
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fetchUser (C:\Users\Dev03\Desktop\uri\main.js:12:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const fetchUser = async id => {
    const response = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/v9/users/(USER ID)', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bot ' + (BOT TOKEN)
        }
    })
    return JSON.stringify(await response.json(), null, 4)
}

fetchUser().then(console.log)
```

You should use `JSON.stringify()` instead of `JSON.parse()` in this scenario, it will return `Promise<pending>` that could been logged with `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fetchUser = async userid => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v9/users/${userid}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bot' + token
    }
  })
  return JSON.parse(await response.json())
}
console.log(fetchUser(id))
```

Comment: It gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
const { get, post } = require('axios');
let { data } = await get("https://discordapp.com/api/v9/users/userid", { headers: { "Authorization": "Bot " + client.token, "Content-Type": "application/json" } });
```

Make sure you are using `async` while using `await`